# Passing a variable to a window already open

Tags: c#, wpf

Context: Creating a custom MessageBox with text input

How can I pass a variable back to my original window from my custom MessageBox window? I know how to do this when opening a new window, but not with one already open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not just grab data from your message box when it closes

```
var msgBox = new MyMessageBox();
If (msgBox.ShowDialog(blah, blah, etc) == true)
{
   var dataBack = msgBox.PropertyThatHasInfo;
}
```

To return a DialogResult from you Window you can just set the DialogResult boollean depending on the user interaction

EG:

```
   public class MyMessageBox : Window
   {

        private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }

        private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = false;
        }
   }
```

Comment: No, that'll work, thanks. However, msgBox.ShowDialog() == true is not returning true. What do I need to do in the code for msgBox to change that?

Comment: If you using a WPF window as your messagebox you can set `DialogResult` to true or false